# How can I Connect these two classes?

Tags: java

How can I connect these two classes with eath other, so "17-0.10" comes out at Class 1?

Class 1:

```
    public class Main { 
        public static int String(int room){

     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Room office = new Room(17, 0, 10);
        Room lecture = new Room(2, 0, 10);
        Room lab = new Room(18, 1, 1);

        System.out.println(office);  // => "17-0.10"
        System.out.println(lecture); // => " 2-0.10"
        System.out.println(lab);     // => "18-1.01"
    }
}
```

Class 2:

```
public class Room {
    public int gebaeude;
    public int etage;
    public int raumnummer;

public Room(int gb, int eg, int rn) {
    this.gebaeude = gb;
    this.etage = eg;
    this.raumnummer = rn;
    }

public String toString() {
    return this.gebaeude + "-" + this.etage + "." + this.raumnummer;
}
}
```

If you asked, i wrote Class 2, and "public static int String(int room)", I am new in Java, the first thing that i tried was just System.out.println (Room);

Comment: What is `public static int String(int room)` supposed to be?? That looks like a VERY bad idea. You define a method which has the same name as the pre-defined class `String`. That being said `System.out.println(office);` is exactly right.

Comment: Everything is fine. Just remove the unnecessary `public static int String(int room){ }` and it works

Comment: @luk2302 It's poor style because it does not follow the usual naming conventions but "VERY bad" is an overstatement.

Comment: You should already be getting a compilation error because of the absence of a return statement in the String method. And adding a return statement or removing that function should fix the issue as the code is just fine.
Not able to understand what issue exactly you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, just remove the String() method in Main class. Everything else is working fine.